# Verify Signature in JS Console

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, signature, verify

In the geth console:

```
eth.sign(eth.accounts[0],web3.sha3('yesyesyall'))
```

**Returns:** "*0x6df4a058e304c2e42032e6b812e268f4d4d4006698f41a2345ed88a161b00e52176b333fb5945dc02e860a4e9c29351eccba19316a82bf86530b977d4629efcf1c*"

How do I verify that was signed by **eth.accounts[0]**?  Everything I see online mentions contracts.

Comment: nah, I didn't know ecrecover existed.  I'm asking for a function like eth.verify('0x6df....', public_key)

Comment: You can use a library for Elliptic Curve Cryptography computations like [elliptic](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/) or [secp256k1](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node) to verify the message. But you will be doing the same computation that ecrecover is doing.